# How to apply multiprocessing in my Python code?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I need help with applying multiprocessing in my code.  I tried reading the multiprocessing section of the Python documentation, but I just don't know how to apply it to what I have.  I believe what I do want to use is Pool, though.  Below is part of one of the python scripts I have written that will eventually be called to another main script:

```
## servoRemote.py

from franges import drange
from cmath import sqrt as csqrt
from math import atan, degrees, radians, tan, sqrt, floor
import servo

# Declare variables for servo conditional statements:
UR = False
UL = False
BR = False
BL = False

def servoControl(x,y):
    global UR, UL, BR, BL
    ytop = round((-csqrt((0.3688**2)*(1-((x-0.5)**2)/(0.2067**2)))+0.5).real,3)
    ybottom = round((csqrt((0.3688**2)*(1-((x-0.5)**2)/(0.2067**2)))+0.5).real,3)

    if (x in list(drange(0.5,0.708,0.001,3)) and y in list(drange(ytop,0.501,0.001,3))):
        UR = True
        UL = False
        BR = False
        BL = False
        (factor, angle) = linearSF(x,y)
        (servo1, servo2) = angleSF(factor,angle)
        servo.move(1,servo1)
        servo.move(2,servo2)

def linearSF(r,s):
    # Calculates the hypotenuse of the gaze:
    distr = abs(r-0.4999)
    dists = abs(0.50-s)
    theta = atan(dists/distr)
    b = sqrt(distr**2+dists**2)

    # Involved in solving for max x coordinate:
    A = 1+0.31412198*tan(theta)**2
    B = (-1-0.31412198*tan(theta)**2)**2 - 4*(1+(tan(theta)**2)/3.183477)*(0.207275+0.0785305*tan(theta)**2)
    B = csqrt(B)
    C = 2+((2*tan(theta)**2)/3.183477)

    # Different x equations:
    xRight = ((A+B)/C).real
    xLeft = ((A-B)/C).real

    if (UR == True and UL == False and BR == False and BL == False):
        x = xRight
        y = -sqrt((0.3688**2)*(1-((x-0.5)**2)/(0.2067**2)))+0.5
    # Solve for max hypotenuse given an angle, a:
    a = sqrt(abs(x-0.5)**2+abs(0.5-y)**2)
    # Final outputs, factor and angle (in degrees):
    factor = (b/float(a))
    angle = degrees(theta)
    return (factor, angle)

def angleSF(factor, angle):
    # Angular factors:
    S1U = -0.0025641026*angle + 1.230759
    S2R = 0.0025641026*angle + 1
    if (UR == True and UL == False and BR == False and BL == False):
        servo1 = int(floor((S1U*65-78)*factor + 78))
        servo2 = int(floor((S2R*65-78)*factor + 78))
    return (servo1,servo2)
```

The code above is only for the case when UR == True.  There are also other conditional if statements that follow with different conditions.  Most of the examples I found using multiprocesses use a finite for loop, but I would like to put this in a while like so:

```
while 1:
    x = [some continuously incoming data stream]
    y = [some continuously incoming data stream]
    servoControl(x,y)
```

Thanks again in advance! I'm sure if I understand how to do it for this one script, I will probably able to figure out how to apply it to the other ones.

Comment: Shared state (your use of globals) doesn't apply well to multiprocessing.

Comment: `foo == False` is spelled `not foo` and `foo == True` is spelled `foo`.

Comment: Is your code too slow? By how much? There is a LOT of optimization and organization you should look into before you'd want to consider parallelization.

Comment: On it's on (this is just the servoControl part) it's fine.  It's when I start running servoControl, camera feed background, and parsing data from an external device is when things start becoming really slow.  Each part as a standalone works just fine though.  I guess for our code, the idea is we:
1) Parse data from incoming device and run a working average
2) Use averaged data in servoControl which move servo motors
3) Have a running background camera feed.

Answer (score 0):

Multiprocessing is a bit daunting. The key thing to understand is that you do not want more than one process using a resource (for example, writing to a reference) when other processes are using it (reading or writing).

So for your ideal multiprocessing setup, you want each process to work only on resources that it alone is using.

So multi-processing in python, can be used effectively when 1) the multiple processes work on different resources and 2) either you have multiple processors on your hardware, or multiple processes can swap between each other on a single (or multiple) processor machine while waiting for events to occur.

I would recommend getting your feet wet experimenting with "some toys" that meet the conditions above to get a feel for how and where it works. Then revisit your problem and try to implement it in a way consistent with how python multiprocessing works.

Read the documentation thoroughly. There is join () function that you will likely need to make sure that all of your processes finish, before whatever the next step might be, even if the next step is just to terminate the program.